# Finding radius of the loop in minimum time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, energy-conservation, friction

[image]

This was my method in solving this question :

Since it is mentioned minimum time,  the ball B ( after recieving 'v' velocity from A) hits C transferring the same v velocity. Due to friction, the velocity dissipates and I assumed it becomes zero at the end of the rough surface. But due to inertia it moves forward and hits A with the velocity gained from potential energy...and so finally A recheaes it's initial point.

So by Work energy theorem
Work done by friction by C = change
in
energy of B

ie, f ( 2πR) /3 = 0.5 mv²
ie, R = 3mv²/4πf

But the answer is option 2 with the only solution at the stating
f [(2πR/3). 3 ] = 0.5 mv²

How did the 3 come in place ?

Comment: You have to do the same reasoning three times for ball a to get back to a - otherwise it stays where it has hit b.

Answer (score 0):

A hits B, B hits C -> C suffers loss in velocity due to friction.

C hits A, A hits B -> B suffers loss in velocity due to friction.

B hits C, C hits A -> A suffers loss in velocity due to friction.

And finally velocity of A becomes 0. Now I think you can see how much work is done by friction.